# Getting exact synonym or antonyms using Wiktionary API

Tags: javascript, jquery, dbpedia, mediawiki-api, wiktionary

I am trying to retrieve synonym and antonyms using Wiktionary API. I am getting some response but it's a bit hazy. I have used this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var page= $( this ).val();
    $.getJSON(baseURL+'/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text|revid|displaytitle|extracts&callback=?&page=' + page,
    function(json) {
      if(json.parse.revid > 0) {                
        //showPage(page,json.parse.text['*']);
                var markup = json.parse.text['*'];
                var blurb = $('<div></div>').html(markup);
                var last = $(blurb).find('p');
        $('#article').html(last);
                console.log(last);
      } else {
         // error code
      }
    });
  });
```

Is it possible to get the exact word? If yes, then I need some clue.

Answer (score 0):

Nemo's 0th rule of wiki development: if you find yourself parsing wikitext, you're doing it wrong.

If you're using the English Wiktionary, you are lucky: you can and should use the [Wiktionary RDF extraction](http://dbpedia.org/Wiktionary) by DBpedia and help improve it as needed. If you need other Wiktionary languages, please contribute to their DBpedia extraction.

Comment: The wiktionary aspect of DBPedia shows signs of neglect or abandonment. Most pages produce 404 errors, and the examples do not return meaning results

Comment: @havlock True. I posted other answers about Wiktionary which may be more relevant now (for some things Wikidata, the new REST API or other systems may be more fruitful now).